# how to show countdown of a timer in Jtextfield using netbeans

Tags: java, countdown

I want to show a countdown timer from 30 sec to 10 sec in `JTextField`.

The countdown will start when the button is clicked.
The countdown must show in JTextField .
When countdown reach to 10 sec it must show message in `JOptionPane` as *"time up"*.

Comment: "using netbeans". Java is Java, no matter what IDE you use.

Comment: 1) What have you tried so far? Do you have any code you could show us? 2) Why is the time up, when the countdown reaches 10 seconds?

Comment: @hamena314 this application is using for a school test paper application,

Comment: @Stultuske i am getting answer in java . but not getting in IDE so i want to know about all of your ideas

Comment: Show your full attempt of doing this and only this.

Comment: what do you mean "not getting in IDE"?

Comment: I am using IDE of 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Your question answer as simple example.

*Note that use below package name (for example: package test)in code window . `import javax.swing.Timer;`* and then enter the following code below the button click.

```
 jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    jTextField2.setEditable(true);
    jTextField3.setText("10");

   Timer t= new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

       int g=9;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

        jTextField3.setText(""+g);

        if(g==0)
        {
            jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    jTextField2.setEditable(false);
            jTextField3.setText("");

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "time up");
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();


        }
        g--;
      }

    });
    t.start();
```

Comment: @user5809644 you can update the codes as you like. I have mention here is an example only. I am running this code in my project and it is working.